# Is it possible to plot a single value point overlay on a box plot with D3

Tags: d3.js, boxplot

I would like to be able to plot a point for a single value on a box plot using D3.js. I have checked out a lot of boxplot posts but can't find an answer.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: Can you give me some idea as to how I should do it.

Comment: Add a `circle` element at the coordinates of the point, assuming you're using SVG.